# How can I pass datasources option in apollo server configuration, when i am creating schema using makeExecutableSchema

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

When I am passing `datasources` to apollo server configuration everything works but graphql playground breaks giving message:

> Server cannot be reached

```
const schema =  makeExecutableSchema({
 typeDefs: [ Users ],
 resolvers: merge(resolvers, userResolvers)
});

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ 
 schema,
 dataSources:()=>({
  usersAPI : new UsersAPI()
 }),
 playground:true,
 introspection:true
});
```